# Show that $\bigcap _{n\epsilon \mathbb{N}}\left [ 0, 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right ] = \left [ 0,1 \right ]$

Tags: calculus

Show that $\bigcap _{n\epsilon \mathbb{N}}\left [ 0, \, \, 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right ] = \left [ 0,1 \right ] $

Comment: Set $A_n=\left[0,1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right]$, we have ${{A}_{1}}\supset {{A}_{2}}\supset \cdots $. Now consider $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{A}_{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $[0,1]\subseteq \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty [0,1+\frac{1}{n}]$ since $[0,1]\subseteq [0,1]$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

We just have to show $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty [0,1+\frac{1}{n}] \subseteq [0,1]$, to so this we have to show that if $x>1$ or if $x<0$ then $x\not \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty [0,1+\frac{1}{n}]$. If $x<0$ then $x\not\in [1,1+\frac{1}{1}]$ and we are done. If $x>1$ then pick $n$ so that $x-1<\frac{1}{n}$, and then we shall have $x\not\in [1,1+\frac{1}{n}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $x \in  \bigcap _{n\epsilon \mathbb{N}}\left [ 0, \, \, 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right ]  $, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, $ $0 \leq x \leq 1+\frac{1}{n+1}.$ Suppose on the contrary that $x>1$, can you use the face that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}=0$ to find a contradiction?

For the opposite direction, note that $\frac{1}{n+1} \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $[0,1] \subset [0,1+\frac{1}{n+1}]$ for each natural number n,

$$[0,1] \subset \bigcap _{n \in \mathbb{N}}[0,1+\frac{1}{n+1}].$$

Let $x$ in $\bigcap _{n \in \mathbb{N}}[0,1+\frac{1}{n+1}]$.

> [1]Then $0 \leq x \leq 1+\frac{1}{n+1}$ for all natural number $n$.

Suppose $x>1$ . By Archimedian Principle, There is natural number $N$ such that $1+\frac{1}{N+1}<x$.

It is contradiction to the fact [1].
So $x\leq 1$.

So
$\bigcap _{n\epsilon \mathbb{N}}\left [ 0, \, \, 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right ] = \left [ 0,1 \right ]$